# Evaluate Quoted Expression in F#

Tags: f#, quotations

I hope I haven't missed something obvious, but I've been playing with F# expressions and I want to evaluate quoted expressions on the fly. For example, I want write something like this:

```
let x = <@ 2 * 5 @>
let y = transform x // replaces op_Multiply with op_Addition, or <@ 2 + 5 @>
let z = eval y // dynamically evaluates y, returns 7
```

**Is there a built-in F# method which can evaluate quoted expressions, or do I have to write my own?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there's no built-in way to compile F# quotations. With the PowerPack LINQ you can convert SOME quotations to .NET System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, and use that to compile them.

Quotations were made to allow other interpretations of code, such as targeting SQL or a GPU card.

However, in posts on hubfs, it's been hinted at that this is a common request and will be looked at.

Answer (score 18):

I've implemented a reflection-based Quotation evaluator as part of [Unquote](http://code.google.com/p/unquote/) (this is a new feature as of version 2.0.0).

```
> #r @"..\packages\Unquote.2.2.2\lib\net40\Unquote.dll"

--> Referenced '..\packages\Unquote.2.2.2\lib\net40\Unquote.dll'

> Swensen.Unquote.Operators.eval <@ sprintf "%A" (1,2) @>;;
val it : string = "(1, 2)"
```

I've measured it to be up to 50 times faster than PowerPack's evaluator. This will, of course, vary by scenario. But Unquote is generally magnitudes faster than PowerPack at interpreting expressions.

It also supports many more expressions than PowerPack's evaluator, including VarSet, PropertySet, FieldSet, WhileLoop, ForIntegerRangeLoop, and Quote. In fact, Unquote's evaluator supports all quotation expressions *except* NewDelegate, AddressSet, and AddressOf all of which I plan on eventually supporting.

Comment: Is there a way to use your library for arbitrary unquoting, without the testing part?

Comment: @ChadZawistowski yes, there are general functions including `decompile`, `reduce`, `reduceAll`, `eval`, and `unquote` available for arbitrary unquoting (decompilation and evaluation of quotations).

Answer (score 8):

You can evaluate an F# quotation using the `Eval` extension member provided by the `FSharp.PowerPack.Linq` DLL as follows:

```
#r "FSharp.PowerPack.Linq.dll"

open Linq.QuotationEvaluation
let f = <@2 + 3@>
f.Eval()
```

Note that you must `open` the `Linq.QuotationEvaluation` namespace to make this extension member available.

There is also a `Compile` extension member that returns a suspension but it does not appear to improve performance.

Comment: +1 Jon, this is the only answer that fully explains how to use PowerPack's evaluator.

Comment: Not sure who downvoted you, but I balanced it out with an upvote for your helpful answer <3

Answer (score 7):

**Updated in 2016**

The `Evaluate` extension method can now be found in NuGet package `FSharp.Quotations.Evaluator`

```
#r "../packages/FSharp.Quotations.Evaluator.1.0.7/lib/net40/FSharp.Quotations.Evaluator.dll"

open FSharp.Quotations.Evaluator

let f = <@ 2 + 3 @>
f.Evaluate()
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the quotations has got a `.eval()`-method.

Comment: +1 although it is actually `Eval`. I don't understand why your and my answers have had three uncommented downvotes...

Comment: what namespace has this?  I'm not seeing it.  Thanks!